# SwiftyStoreKit IAP Purchasing but not remembering it's settings after launch

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, swiftystorekit

I am trying to integrate a very basic single IAP in my game, here I am calling from my `GameScene`

```
 let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Upgrade", message: "Would you like to remove ads?", preferredStyle: .alert)

                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Remove Ads", style: .default, handler: { action in
                    print("Pressed Remove Ads")
                    
                    GameViewController().buytheIAP()
                    
                }))
                
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Restore Purchases", style: .default, handler: { action in
                    print("Pressed Restore")
                    GameViewController().restoretheIAP()
                }))
                
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: { action in
                    print("Pressed Cancel")
                }))
              
                view?.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                      }
```

Those methods are called correctly, and refer to these inside `GameViewController.swift`;

```
func buytheIAP(){
         
         iAPHelper.purchase()
         print("OK Lets upgrade")
    }
    
    func restoretheIAP(){
        
         iAPHelper.restorePurchase()
         print("OK Lets restore")
    }
    
    func restoreDidSucceed() {
     
        UserDefaults.setValue(true, forKey: iAPHelper.productID)
        //this should have something like hide banner etc.
         bannerView.isHidden = true
    }
    
    func purchaseDidSucceed() {
        UserDefaults.setValue(true, forKey: iAPHelper.productID)
        //as above this should have something like hide banner etc.
         
         bannerView.isHidden = true
         
         print("Purchased upgrade ENJOYYYYYYYY")
         
    }
    
    func nothingToRestore() {
        
    }
    
    func paymentCancelled() {
        
    }
```

The test IAP goes through, it gets the correct information from the app store, and I use my sandbox details to purchase, it goes through correctly with a successful purchase message. However, the `bannerView` does not hide, and more importantly, upon restarting the game again, everything is forgotten and the game thinks nothing has been purchased. I am guessing it has to be some sort of check that is missing.

I have this in my `viewDidLoad`

```
 if userDefaults.bool(forKey: iAPHelper.productID) {
                   
              bannerView.isHidden = true
              print("It is purchased, so DO NOT show the ads")
         } else{
         
         bannerView.adSize = getAdaptiveSize()
         bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
         bannerView.delegate = self
         bannerView.rootViewController = self
         bannerView.load(GADRequest())
         addBannerViewToView(bannerView)
              
              print("Not purchased, so show the ads")
              
         }
```

And it ALWAYS shows `print("Not purchased, so show the ads")`

The `IAPHelper` file, for purchasing is;

```
 func purchase() {
        
        SwiftyStoreKit.purchaseProduct(productID, quantity: 1, atomically: true) { [self] result in
            switch result {
            case .success:
                
                delegate?.purchaseDidSucceed()
                print("OK It's purchased")
                
            case .error(let error):
                switch error.code {
                case .unknown: print("Unknown error. Please contact support")
                case .clientInvalid: print("Not allowed to make the payment")
                case .paymentCancelled:
                    
                    delegate?.paymentCancelled()
                    
                case .paymentInvalid: print("The purchase identifier was invalid")
                case .paymentNotAllowed: print("The device is not allowed to make the payment")
                case .storeProductNotAvailable: print("The product is not available in the current storefront")
                case .cloudServicePermissionDenied: print("Access to cloud service information is not allowed")
                case .cloudServiceNetworkConnectionFailed: print("Could not connect to the network")
                case .cloudServiceRevoked: print("User has revoked permission to use this cloud service")
                default: print((error as NSError).localizedDescription)
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the log DOES show  `print("OK It's purchased")` after the initial purchase - so I am struggling to see what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I figured the answer, there was a missing line in my `AppDelegate.swift` section `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["adRemove" : false])
```

I renamed `userDefaults.bool(forKey: iAPHelper.productID)` to make it easier to use / understand. So in my original post that has been replaced by  `UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["adRemove" : false])` instead.

You can then use this anywhere to check, such as;

```
if !userDefaults.bool(forKey: "adRemove") {
// Do something here
}
```

Hope this helps anyone in future with the same question!

Answer (score 0):

The IAP delegate functions are not (guaranteed to be) called on the UI/main thread, that's why your view doesn't hide.

Don't you see some iOS warning saying that you try to set a `UIView` property on non-main thread?

The fact that your custom purchase info was not saved in `UserDefaults` could be caused by killing the app prematurely from Xcode.

(`UserDefaults` does take of saving what's being set during normal app flow.)

Comment: No warnings about `UIView` - I do let the app run for a while before closing it again to test, it's very strange - I could perhaps add an observer to send a hide banner message, but that still wouldn't solve the failure to remember the settings in `UserDefaults` ?

Comment: @DannyRoy just set a breakpoint and see in what thread you're hiding this view.

Comment: Interesting - it seems the `func purchaseDidSucceed() { }` is not being called even after successful purchase - so that delegate method for some reason not firing off. Which explains why the `UserDefaults` are not being saved and the `bannerView`not hiding.